# Limit as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ of $\frac{x^2\sin(x)}{x^2 + y^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I need to find
$$\lim_{(x.y) \to (0,0)}\frac{x^2 \sin(x)}{x^2 + y^2}$$ 
Wolfram says that this limit is undefined. However, I attempted to solve this and I got that the limit is $0$. Therefore, I'd be grateful if you could tell me where my reasoning went wrong. 
Since the limit is at the origin, I can apply polar coordinates: 
$$\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{r^2 \sin^2(\theta) \sin(r \sin(\theta))}{r^2(\sin^2(\theta)+\cos^2(\theta))} = \lim_{r \to 0}\sin^2(\theta) \sin(r \sin(\theta))$$
Now, we know that this expression $\sin(\theta) $ is bounded. Therefore $r \sin(\theta)$ approaches $0$ since $r$ approaches $0$. This entails that $\sin(r \sin(\theta)) $ approaches $0$ because $\sin(0) = 0$. Finally. $\sin^2(\theta) $ is bounded, and so the limit in questoin becomes $0$. 
Where is the error in my reasoning?

Comment: I don't think your reasoning is wrong. Wolfram most likely is mistaken here

Comment: Your title and body disagree. The titular limit does not exist, while the body limit does.

Comment: @user296602  Thank you, I have corrected the typo in the title.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct.

Comment: @user296602 https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+as+(x,y)+approach+(0,0)+of+x%5E2+sin(x)+%2F+(x%5E2+%2B+y%5E2)

Comment: Maybe you should ask this at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com -- it does seem perplexing that WA can't find the limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that $\forall x\ne 0$ and $\forall y\in\Bbb R,$

$$x^2+y^2\ge x^2>0$$

$$\implies $$

$$|\frac{x^2\sin (x)}{x^2+y^2}|\le |\sin (x)|$$

thus the limit is zero.

Answer (score 3):

$| { x^2 \sin x \over x^2+y^2}| \le| { x^3 \over x^2+y^2}| \le |x|  | { x^2 \over x^2+y^2}| \le |x|$.